# Web service authentication through DomainServiceContext in RIA Services

Tags: wcf, web-services, silverlight, ria, networkcredentials

I did a Silverlight RIA Bussiness application. The server side requieres authentication and is going over https.

From the server side, I want to acces to an external web service which also needs credentials and also goes over https. The point is that the required credentials for the web service are the same the credentials required for the RIA business service.

I would like to:

1.-To create an intance of the web service in the RIA service business application service side

2.- Set the web service credentials = RIA service business application credentials (which are, obvisuly, already authenticated)

My untuiton says that there must be a way to do this but I have no idea how. Anyway, my untuition has been wrong so many times...